# How to change stroke of SVG (imported as react component) on hover of parent element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using `react` + `tailwindcss v3`, but I am unable to figure out how could I change the SVG stroke color on `hover` of its parent element.

This is the code where I have rendered the SVG `component`

```js
import Arrow from "../../assets/logos/Arrow_up_right";

const MyComponent= () => {
    const onhover = "blue";
    const normal = "red";

    return (
       <ul className='list-none px-2'>
          <li> className='my-2 h-12 w-12 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gray-100 hover:cursor-pointer'>
             <Arrow stroke={normal} />
          </li>
       </ul>
};
```

`Arrow` is the component which returns SVG. I have passed a `prop` to it which then is used in providing `color` to stroke of `arrow` svg.

here is the SVG component:

```js
const Arrow_up_right = ({ stroke }) => {
    return (
        <svg
            width='8'
            height='8'
            viewBox='0 0 8 8'
            fill='none'
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        >
            <path
                d='M0.666626 7.33335L7.33329 0.666687M7.33329 0.666687H0.666626M7.33329 0.666687V7.33335'
                stroke={stroke}
                stroke-linecap='round'
                stroke-linejoin='round'
            />
        </svg>
    );
};

export default Arrow_up_right;
```

***The Problem now*** is I want the value of `prop` being passed should change on `hover` of `li`,
if that can't be done then please suggest some other way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you using tailwind class to set the stroke color?

Comment: No stroke is added as a we generally add in normal `SVG` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach with **CSS Variables** and **Tailwind Utilities**, where we pass initial values from the parent component to the child and then use an extra class in the parent `<li>`.

[image]

##### index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .arrow svg path {
    stroke: var(--normal);
  }
  ,
  .arrow:hover svg path {
    stroke: var(--hover);
  }
}
```

##### Arrow.jsx

```
export const Arrow = ({ strokeColor, strokeHover }) => {
  return (
    <svg width="8" height="8" viewBox="0 0 8 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M0.666626 7.33335L7.33329 0.666687M7.33329 0.666687H0.666626M7.33329 0.666687V7.33335"
        style={{ '--normal': strokeColor, '--hover': strokeHover }}
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

##### App.jsx

```
function App() {
  const onhover = 'blue';
  const normal = 'red';

  return (
    <div className="p-6">
      <ul className="list-none px-2">
        <li className="my-2 h-12 w-12 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gray-100 hover:cursor-pointer arrow hover:arrow">
          <Arrow strokeColor={normal} strokeHover={onhover} />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` together with `useState` to set hover state and based on that pass correct color to `Arrow`.

But in my opinion better way would be to utilize tailwind `group` class. You can set `group` class on `li` and then in the `Arrow_up_right` component use tailwind stroke classes `stroke-red-500 group-hover:stroke-blue-500` (change number to match your desired color) on `svg` tag and remove stroke from `path`.

Answer (score 0):

I found one more way by which I solved my issue

what you can do is:

```js
import Arrow from "../../assets/logos/Arrow_up_right";

const MyComponent= () => {

    return (
       <ul className='list-none px-2'>
          <li>
             <Button className='my-2 h-12 w-12 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gray-100 hover:cursor-pointer'>
                <Arrow />
             </Button>
          </li>
       </ul>
};
```

**index.css**

```
li:hover svg>path {
    stroke: #4352FF;
}
```

for any other element nesting:

```
import Arrow from "../../assets/logos/Arrow_up_right";

const MyComponent= () => {

    return (
       <div className='list-none px-2'>
          <button className="calender flex items-center gap-2 py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-primary hover:text-primary hover:bg-white hover:border hover:border-primary focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-primary mr-3">
                <Calender />
                Add To Calender
          </button>
       </div>
};
```

**index.css**

```css
.calender:hover svg>path {
    stroke: #4352FF;
}
```